# How to replace a string with data, from 2 arrays, in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, search, intersection

I have a simple string: `char *StrOne = "There is my text.";`. And, I have 2 simple arrays, too:

```
char ArrOne[][2] = {

    {1, 'a'},
    {7, 'e'},
    {5, 'c'},
    {4, 'x'},
    {2, 'r'}

};
```

-

```
char ArrTwo[][2] = {

    {7, 'k'},
    {9, 'z'},
    {1, 'y'},
    {3, 'x'},
    {2, 'b'}

};
```

---

I want to replace `StrOne` with values from `ArrOne`, by values from `ArrTwo`. There is my idea:

- Step 1. If there is a char in `StrOne` (what is existed in `ArrOne`), search in `ArrTwo` what value is attached which the same key  (what is existed in `ArrOne`).
- Step 2. Replace all existed values (from **Step 1.**).
- Step 3. Display new output string  (which is replaced completely, from **Step 2.**).

The output string is: `char *StrTwo = "Thkrk is my tkxt.";`.

---

How to create a simple C function, that it will do it like this?

Comment: Because your question is off-topic since it does not show any code. You should show some [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Then you are asking on the wrong place. SO is not a homework (or program writing) service.

Comment: Read a good C programming book, then use a good [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (e.g. `emacs` or `vim`) with a good compiler such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use a debugger (`gdb`) to run your program step by step. Improve your source code. Repeat all this till you are satisfied.

Comment: "Write code for me that does X" is not a question.

Comment: Make a little foundation program. I.e. start by writing a loop which just prints each of the input chars. Then change it to replace any char which occurrs in  ArrOne by "_". Then change to replace by the corresponding index of Arr1. Then change to replace by the number in Arr1. Then change to not replace, if the number is not in Arr2. Then change to replace by the index in Arr2. Then change to replace by the letter at that index in Arr2. Then change to ... oops - done. If you get stuck, show the code you have at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Since characters have a limited range, you can construct a look-up table that translates characters from the original string to the replacement string in a single run.

Make `ArrOne` and `ArrTwo` unsigned, then make translation table in three steps:

1. Make array `one[]` with the numeric key of characters that need to be replaced in positions of character that need to be replaced,
2. Make array `two[]` with the new character in the position of the numeric key
3. Make a translation for each character with the replacement character in the position of the original character

Here is how this looks in code:

```
// Step 1
unsigned char one[128] = {0};
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    one[ArrOne[i][1]] = ArrOne[i][0];
}
// Step 2
char two[128] = {0};
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    two[ArrTwo[i][0]] = ArrTwo[i][1];
}
// Step 3
char lookup[128];
for (int c = 0 ; c != 128 ; c++) {
    char r = two[one[c]];
    lookup[c] = r ? r : c;
}
```

Now the string can be converted in a single loop:

```
char str[] = "There is my text.";
printf("%s\n", str);
for (char *p = str ; *p ; p++) {
    *p = lookup[(int)*p];
}
printf("%s\n", str);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/wZLwf2)